# Compact manifold/Morse theory

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I have a question concerning the proof of theorem 3.5 in Milnor's Morse Theory.

This theorem states that if $f$ is a differentiable function on a Manifold M with no critical points, and if each $M^a = \{x\in M | f(x)\leq a \} $ is compact then $M$ has the homotopy type of a CW-complex with one cell of dimension $\lambda$ for each critical point of index $\lambda$

Basically the proof shows via induction and appealing to previous theorems that $M^a$ has the homotopy type of a CW complex satisfying the conclusion above. But then Milnor says "If $M$ is compact this completes the proof".

I don't understand how this just follows directly? Is there some theorem involving Compact manifolds or CW complexes that I am missing?  Does $M^a$ have to be homotopic to $M$ for some $a$ if $M$ is compact?

Comment: Presumably in your 2nd paragraph you mean to say $f$ is a Morse function, not that $f$ has no critical points?

Comment: I merged your two unregistered accounts. Please try to remember to log in using the same credentials so you can at least post comments as comments, and not as answers.

Answer (score 6):

If $M$ is compact, one of the $M^a$ is *equal* to $M$!

Comment: Basically this is because you can Just take a= max f which is achieved since $M$ is compact. Then $M^a = M$ and since $M^a$ has the correct form for all $a$,thus so does $M$?

Comment: @anonymous: exactly.